# the main and the navbar divs are overlapping, I want them to appear side by side

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx, antd

```
<div className="App">
      
      <div className="navbar">
        <Navbar></Navbar>
        </div>
       
      <div className="main">
        <Layout>
          <div className = "routes">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path = "/">
              <Homepage/>
            </Route>
            <Route path = "/exchanges">
              <Exchanges/>
            </Route>
            <Route exact path = "/cryptocurrencies">
              <Cryptocurrencies/>
            </Route>
            <Route path = "/crypto/:coinId">
              <CryptoDetails/>
            </Route>
            <Route path = "/news">
              <News/>
            </Route>
          </Switch>

          </div>
        
        </Layout>
        
      <div className="footer">
        <Typography.Title level = {5} style = {{color:"white"}} align = "center">
          The CryptoVerse <br/>
          All rights reserved @2021<br/> made by Utkrisht
        </Typography.Title>
        <Space>
          <Link to = "/">Home</Link>
          <Link to = "/exchanges">Exchanges</Link>
          <Link to = "/news">News</Link>
        </Space>
      </div>
      
     </div>
     
    </div>
```

Below is the css for the code

I want the navbar and the main divs to appear just side by side so that the content of the main page can be displayed beside the navbar. But right now, the main div and the navbar divs are overlapping and because of this the content is being hidden by the navbar.

```
.app{
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar{
    flex: 0.2;
    background-color: rgb(0, 21, 41);
    
}

.main{
    flex: 0.8;
    width: 100%;
   
    
}
.routes{
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`CSS` is case-sensitive. In your `HTML` you've got this:

```html
<div className="App">
  …
</div>
```

And your `CSS` is attempting to style it using this:

```css
.app { 
  …
}
```

You'll need to match cases using this:

```css
.App { 
  …
}
```